# How to import/export file in coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Actually we are working two people on a single project having coredata functionality.
We both created different tables within coredata in two different system.
Now how can we merge this two tables into a single coredata project.

I didn't find any import/export file options in coredata.

Please help us we are under water.......

Comment: Please describe the issue you are having in more detail. What exactly are you trying to do? Make this clear in your question so people are able to answer it.

Comment: Please see this screenshots.I want to add Contacts Entities from one coredata file to another coredata file                       (https://plus.google.com/photos/105918944612452393134/albums/5881557743791382673?banner=pwa)

Comment: You could open both data models in a text editor (browse the contents of the data model file package and find a file called 'contents'), and copy and paste the bits you need from one to the other, since they are XML files and quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

This post has a good example of creating a database programmatically.

[How to create sqlite database programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545520/how-to-create-sqlite-database-programmatically)

You'll want to open both databases in a throw-away program, then write the combined tables out to the programmatically created database file.