# How to create an Sqlite3 database - IOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Okay so I am trying create an IOS APP that uses a sqlite database so it can store the users username and can tell if he is logged in or not. The problem is I have also made an Android app that has a database. So when I open the command prompt for sqlite3 it already has me logged into a database. How can I leave this database to create a new one?

When I open the sqlite3 command prompt it tells me this message

```
Last login: Thu Sep 26 12:52:47 on ttys000
Bobs-MacBook-Pro:~ Bob$ /Applications/Android\ Development/sdk/tools/sqlite3 ; exit;
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

How can I leave the android database so I can create an IOS one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's sqlite3 man page:

> To start a sqlite3 interactive session, invoke the sqlite3 command and optionally provide the name of
>          a database file.  If the database file does not exist, it will be created.  If the database file does
>          exist, it will be opened.

So you could do

```
sqlite3 mydata.db
```

and if mydata.db doesn't exist it will be created.

[sqlite3 man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sqlite3.1.html)

You can also skip the command-line and create the database in code.  See the answers here:
[How to create sqlite database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545520/how-to-create-sqlite-database-programmatically)

Or you could use CoreData,

Answer (score 0):

Try [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). If anything You don't like You always can rewrite this code as example.